# Is there anyway to check if cursor is on pumvisible suggestion or not?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, functions

I wrote the function below,

https://github.com/ryuta69/dotfiles/blob/master/dotfiles/.vimrc#L129-L146

```
fun! DeoEnter()
    if !pumvisible()
        return "\n"
    endif

    if vsnip#available(1)
        call vsnip#expand()
        return "\<C-y>"
    endif

    call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippetOrJump()
    if g:ulti_expand_or_jump_res > 0
        return ""
    endif

    return "\<C-y>"
endfun
ino <CR> <C-R>=DeoEnter()<CR>
```

, however, I found it should separate conditions if the cursor is on pumvisible suggestions. neosnippet has `neosnippet#expandable`, however deoplete itself seems not to have such a function.

Any idea is appreciated.